# GROUP rows between starting trigger and finishing trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would be cool if you could help me with my problem. I have a table where you can see events from a game. Every player has some amount of gold which you can see in a `Value` column after `Log in`. I need to find out with how much gold people start playing their FIRST game after `Log in`. Before players start the game they can `Buy gold` or `Get bonus` which will raise their amount of gold by `Value`

```
**Player ID      Timestamp      Action     Value**    
    1111           09:11        Log in      500
    1111           09:25        Buy gold    100
    1111           09:28        Get bonus    50
    1111           09:30        Start game      
    2222           11:14        Log in      800
    3333           12:01        Log in      700
    3333           12:04        Get bonus    50
    3333           12:08        Start game   
    3333           12:15        Buy gold    100
    3333           12:18        Start game
    1111           14:40        Log in      300
    1111           14:42        Buy gold    100
    1111           14:50        Start game
    2222           15:22        Log in      600
    2222           15:25        Buy gold    100
    2222           16:25        Log in      400
    2222           16:30        Get bonus    50
    2222           16:35        Start game
```

Te result I am looking for is something like that. It is basically a SUM of Values between `Start game` and the most recent `Log in` of a player.

```
**Match number   Player ID     Value**
     1             1111         650
     2             3333         750
     3             1111         400
     4             2222         450
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is Match Number a field in your base table?

Comment: @Gorionovic .. . You say two different things in the two paragraphs.  The first paragraph says "I need to find out with how much gold people start playing their FIRST game after Log in".  The second says "It is basically a SUM of Values between Start game and the most recent Log in of a player".  I think the example data is more consistent with the first definition, but can you fix the question to clarify what you mean?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Please add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to search for each `Log in` row.  Then look up the next row that's either `Log in` or `Start game`.  If that row is a `Start game`, you have a pair that identifies the first game after a login.  You can then find the sum of values for all rows between that pair:

```
select  row_number() over (order by start.Timestamp) as MatchNumber
,       start.[Player ID]
,       vals.SumValue
from    YourTable login
cross apply
        (
        select  top 1 *
        from    YourTable start
        where   login.[Player ID] = start.[Player ID]
                and login.Timestamp < start.Timestamp 
                and start.Action in ('Start game', 'Log in')
        order by
                start.Timestamp
        ) start
cross apply
        (
        select  sum(cast(vals.Value as int)) as SumValue
        from    YourTable vals
        where   vals.[Player ID] = start.[Player ID]
                and vals.Action in ('Log in', 'Get bonus', 'Buy gold')
                and vals.Timestamp between login.Timestamp and start.Timestamp
        ) vals
where   login.Action = 'Log in'
        and start.Action = 'Start game'
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bfced/6/0)

Answer (score 1):

You could try some correlated subquery:

```
SELECT PlayerID, SUM(value) FROM table a
WHERE
TimeStamp >= (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM table WHERE a.PlayerID = PlayerID AND Action = 'Log in' )
GROUP BY PlayerID
```

Comment: The example data clearly shows two rows for 1111, so grouping by PlayerId doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complicated.  My approach is to find, for each login, the next time stamp which is a "login" or "start game" and then join back to the original table to find all the gold entries.

```
select tli.playerId, tli.TimeStamp, sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 timestamp
              from t t2
              where t2.playerId = t.playerId and
                    t2.timestamp > t.timestamp and
                    t2.action in ('log in', 'start game')
              order by timestamp
             ) as nextTimestamp
      from t
      where t.action in ('log in')
     ) tli join
     t
     on t.playerId = tli.playerId and
        t.timestamp >= tli.timestamp and
        t.timestamp < tli.nextTimeStamp
group by tli.playerId, tli.timeStamp
```

Comment: The subquery with `top` needs an `order by`.  This also sums more than it should for two logins followed by one start game.

Comment: Still sums more than it should, see player 2222 in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28d55/2/0)

Comment: @Andomar . . . I must be missing something.  The values 800, 700, and 450 look correct for player 2222.

Comment: Only the first game after a login should count.  Have a look at the example output in the question.